# Is Hermitian matrix a self-adjoint operator w.r.t. just the standard inner product, or any inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Given a linear map $L:V→V$ over an inner product space $(V,〈⟩)$, the adjoint of $L$, denoted by $L^*$, is a linear map $L^*:V→V$ s.t. $〈Lx,y⟩=〈x,L^* y⟩$ for any $x,y\in V$. $L$ is self adjoint if $L=L^*$ and then $〈Lx,y⟩=〈x,Ly⟩$.

Just consider $V=\Bbb C^n$. I am confused by Hermtian matrix. It is easy to prove a Hermitian matrix $H$ is self-adjoint under the standard inner product $〈x,y⟩=y^*x$, by $〈Hx,y⟩=y^*Hx=(H^*y)^*x=(Hy)^*x=〈x,Hy⟩$, but I am not sure if it is actually self adjoint for any inner product. If not, it would be great if someone could help give a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless $H$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, the answer is **always** "no". Just take any positive definite matrix $A$ that doesn't commute with $H$ and define $\langle x,y\rangle=y^\ast Ax$. For $v\mapsto Hv$ to be self-adjoint with respect to this inner product, you need $y^\ast AHx=\langle Hx,y\rangle=\langle x,Hy\rangle=y^\ast HAx$ for any two vectors $x$ and $y$, but that would imply $AH=HA$, which by assumption is false.

Comment: What if there exist matrix which is positive and commute

Comment: @MeetPatel It doesn't matter whether $A$ commutes with some $H$. What matters is whether $A$ does **not** commute with some $H$. If $A$ is not a scalar matrix, such an $H$ can always be found.

Comment: U mean for Hermitian matrix $H$ (not a scalar multiple of identity),and arbitrary complex inner product space $V$ (rather than usual) .  operator of that $H$ w.r.t any basis will never be self adjoint

Comment: @MeetPatel I've mixed up $A$ and $H$ in my previous comment. What I meant was that if $H$ is not a scalar matrix, we can always find an inner product with respect to which $H$ isn't self-adjoint. Since the OP was talking about the special case $V=\mathbb C^n$, the basis (namely, the standard basis) had already been chosen...

Comment: ...Of course, this implies that given any finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb C$, any inner product $q$ defined on $V$ and any linear endomorphism $L:V\to V$ that is self-adjoint with respect to $q$, if $L$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity map, then there exists another inner product on $V$ with respect to which $L$ is not self-adjoint.

Comment: i am still confused ! where i am stucked is , Let $H$ be any $n\times n$ hermitian matrix.and $V$ be any complex inner product space which has dimension $n$.and let $B$ be orthonormal basis w.r.t that inner product.then $B$ and $H$ will gives us operator say $T$ on $V$. then this $T$ has to be self adjoint.then what the question is different here asked by user?

Comment: @MeetPatel The difference is that, your $H$ is a matrix representation of the linear operator $T$ with respect to the basis $B$ that is orthonormal with respect to the given inner product, while the OP's $H$ is a matrix representation of a linear operator with respect to the standard basis.